# Story with mythical Beast being a... tank

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a book, that was part of the series - I've only read the first volume and never had a chance to find the rest.

- Action takes place probably in the future, in Europe but technology
  is medieval again and there is some basic magic
- Main character accidentally finds the legendary Beast, which is in fact a still operational tank (although without any ammo)
- Current ruler is a typical Evil Overlord - there is a small scale rebellion that (so far unsuccessfully) tries to overthrow him, they rally behind the main character and the Beast
- I remember a village that had two magic stones: one allowed you to open any door, second was used to summon lightning.

I've read it probably in the early 90s.

Comment: Main character = A Tank - Maybe a [Bolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolo_(tank)) short story?

Comment: Main character is not a tank, he finds one :)

Comment: @Richard: I was also thinking of Keith Laumer's short story [*Night of the Trolls,*](http://everything2.com/title/The+Night+of+the+Trolls) one of the BOLO stories.

Comment: if not for the magic stones, that would have been "Inhabited island" by Strugatsky.

Comment: Did anyone else read the title and immediately think "Dr. No"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the [*Empire of the East* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_of_the_East_series) by [Fred Saberhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Saberhagen). Specifically the first book, *The Broken Lands*.

The series is set in a future version of Earth. Years ago, mankind stopped a nuclear war by deploying devices which changed the laws of nature. The change had the side effect of introducing magic and magical creatures to the world. Aside from the magic, society regressed to a medieval society.

The protagonist of *The Broken Lands* is a young man who finds what he thinks is an Elephant--actually a nuclear-powered tank--parked in a cave. He manages to get it running and uses it to join the battle against the bad guys.

Google books has a page for [the collected edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=QdLHYMa2Yr4C) of the series. Parts of the book are [available to be viewed](https://books.google.com/books?id=QdLHYMa2Yr4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). You can search on "Elephant" to see some passages involving the tank.

Saberhagen's [*Book of Swords* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_Swords) is set thousands of years later in the same universe as *Empire of the East*. If you enjoy one series, you should take a look at the other.

Comment: bleah, @imaginaryevents beat me by less than a minute!

Comment: haha and who should I now credit for the right answer?

Comment: I have both the original three-volume version of the trilogy and the one-volume collection.  I just wanted to note that there are some significant abridgments to the omnibus edition, and quite a few changes to the last volume (including changing the name from Changeling Earth to Ardneh's World.  In general, I find the original texts to be noticeably better.

Answer (score 17):

[*The Broken Lands*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7399343-the-broken-lands-empire-of-the-east-1) by Fred Saberhagen, published 1968. The first novel in the *Empire of the East* series.

> In the distant future, society has crumbled. Dark forces now rule the land, keeping all humans under their oppressive thumbs.
>   In the darkness of the shadows and whispered on the winds, there is talk of a rebellion. In the swamps, a small band has formed. Determined to regain their freedom, the rebellion, heavily outnumbered, plans to overthrow an army of thousands . . . with the help of one incredible weapon.
>   It is only a legend, a story left over from the Old World before magic and the wizards came to the land. A weapon of technology. It is the mystical Elephant, and whoever masters it holds the key to freedom, or defeat.

[image]